# A quick question about addition step when proving vector subspaces

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, linear-algebra

$$U = \{X\in\text{Real}^{2\times2};\begin{bmatrix}
0 &1 \\
2 & 1\\
\end{bmatrix}X = X\begin{bmatrix}
0 &1 \\
2 & 1\\
\end{bmatrix}\}$$

My question is, when I wanted to show that it is a vector subspace, can I do the following:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
0 &1 \\
2 & 1\\
\end{bmatrix}X_1 + \begin{bmatrix}
0 &1 \\
2 & 1\\
\end{bmatrix}X_2 = X_1\begin{bmatrix}
0 &1 \\
2 & 1\\
\end{bmatrix}+X_2\begin{bmatrix}
0 &1 \\
2 & 1\\
\end{bmatrix}$$
I written this equation, and then factored out the matrices (distributive property) and seen that it holds. Is this enough for addition property when proving that it is a subspace. (The alternative that I could think of is, that I would actually compute X, but I want to see your thoughts on the upper approach)

Comment: Looks good to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks good. You should definitely not try to actually compute all possible $X$ for this problem. But to write it properly, you should not start with
$$\begin{bmatrix}
0 &1 \\
2 & 1\\
\end{bmatrix}X_1 + \begin{bmatrix}
0 &1 \\
2 & 1\\
\end{bmatrix}X_2 = X_1\begin{bmatrix}
0 &1 \\
2 & 1\\
\end{bmatrix}+X_2\begin{bmatrix}
0 &1 \\
2 & 1\\
\end{bmatrix}.$$

Instead, I would write it like this:

Let $A = \begin{bmatrix}
0 &1 \\
2 & 1\\
\end{bmatrix}.$
Take $X_1, X_2 \in U$. We will show $X_1 + X_2 \in U:$
$$A(X_1 + X_2) = AX_1 + AX_2 = X_1A + X_2A = (X_1 + X_2)A.$$
Therefore $X_1 + X_2 \in U$.

Comment: If I would want to know the dimension of this subspace, then I would have to actually compute X right ?

Comment: @BiliDebili Not necessarily. Without computing all possible $X$, I can tell you that this subspace has dimension $3$. $\mathbb{R}^{2 \times 2}$ has dimension $4$, so $\dim U \le 4$. It cannot be $4$, because $U \not = \mathbb{R}^{2 \times 2}$ (you can find a matrix which doesn't commute with $A$). So $\dim U \le 3$. Now $I, A, A^2$ are in $U$ and you can check that they are independent, so $\dim(U) = 3$.

Comment: When I tried to solve what is the dimension of this subspace, I tried to do it with computing the matrix and I got two basis matrices and thus the dimension is 2. In solutions it also says that the dimension should be 2. This may be a solution error or?

Comment: $A^2=A+2I$, so $I,A,A^2$ is a linearly dependent set, no?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Oh thanks I must've messed up my calculations.

Comment: @BiliDebili I think I made a mistake in my calculations. Yes, since my approach didn't work, the only way I can think to do it is to find all elements of $U$. But there might be another clever, but elementary way to do it. There might also be an advanced theorem from abstract algebra that could be used to solve this.

Comment: @GerryMyerson If you don't mind me asking, are you in any way related to the retired Gerry Myerson? https://math.stackexchange.com/users/8269/gerry-myerson

Comment: That's me. I somehow lost access to that account, so I opened a new one about a year ago.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Ah okay thanks for the response